# Как определить что опция getopts не задана

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Есть bash скрипт:

```
while getopts "e:mc:" OPTION ; do
    case "$OPTION" in
            e) tr -dc '0' < /dev/random | head -c "$OPTARG"K > file.txt
            ;;
            m) mount
            ;;
            c) ln "$OPTARG" hardlinktofile
            ;;
            \?) echo "Неверный аргумент"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Каким спец аргументом можно проверить то, что никакой опции было не задано и выполнить заданную команду.

Те при вводе "bash script" без опции (-..) он должен вывести "Опция не задана"

Пытался " :) echo Опция не задана ", не получилось

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50563/110559

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать

```
man getopts
```

то можно прочитать:

> When  the  end  of options is encountered, getopts exits with a return
> value greater than zero. OPTIND is set to the index of the first
> non-option argument, and name is set to ?.